# How to open a file in my app from file manager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio

I have developed a photo viewer app in Android studio but when I try to open an image from file manager, it don't show my app in the app list. How can I add my app to the app selection popup? and what I should do to successfully open it in my app?

Comment: You must declare a special intent in your app. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in your manifest file

```
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```